# delete first n characters of a very large file in unix shell

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a large text file (~3GB). 
While creating it, I made a mistake and the **first few** (not all) characters **of the first line only** are wrong. The rest of the characters in the first line are correct. All the other lines are also correct. My, quite simple, question is:

How do I remove the first n characters of such a large file? **I don't want to delete the whole first line,** only the first n characters. My requirements are:

1. Without replacing all the remaining lines.
2. Without reading the whole file.
3. Ideally, using unix shell commands.

I have tried sed, but this replaces the first line and copies all the rest... Maybe I could use the "quit" option?
Of course, I could create the file again, without making that mistake...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove the first line of a text file using bash/sed script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339483/how-can-i-remove-the-first-line-of-a-text-file-using-bash-sed-script)

Comment: @CiroSantilli how is that a duplicate??? I don't want to delete the first line...

Comment: Same principle: how to efficiently remove from front of file. Answer: not possible in Linux AFAIK.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072180/truncating-the-first-100mb-of-a-file-in-linux

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072180/truncating-the-first-100mb-of-a-file-in-linux Summary: removing data from the beginning of a file without modifying the rest is hard.

Comment: If you are worried about having enough eyes seeing this and providing a good answer, you can wait a couple of days and offer a bounty. Editing over and over again won't help much.

Comment: @fedorqui I 'll just wait a few hours. I didn't edit the question to get better answers, just to make it clearer for future reference :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed -i.bak -r '1s/^.{10}//' file
```

This will create a backup `file.bak` and remove the first 10 characters from the first line. Note `-i` alone can also be used, to do in-place edit without backup.

#### Test

Original file:

```
$ cat a
1234567890some bad data and here we are
blablabla
yeah
```

Let's:

```
$ sed -i.bak -r '1s/^.{10}//' a
$ cat a
some bad data and here we are
blablabla
yeah
$ cat a.bak 
1234567890some bad data and here we are
blablabla
yeah
```

Comment: +1 Good answer, thanks. However, it deletes the first 10 characters and then copies the rest of the file.

Comment: Well, you can also remove these characters in the first line like this: `sed -r '1{s/^.{10}//;q}' file > new_file`, which redirects to another file. Then use `tail -n +2 file >> new_file` to get everything from the 2nd line and finally `mv new_file file` to replace the original one.

Comment: Good point, too! However, the functionality I would want ideally would be: delete the first n characters, stop. What you describe is more like: delete the first n characters, copy the rest of the file, stop. Right?

Comment: Well, I don't think there is such thing. Note that deleting content from the beginning of the file implies moving the rest of it.

Comment: @vefthym Whether you take MS Word or vi editor, if you delete some characters from the beginning the subsequent characters are automatically moved to the front.

Comment: You are both right, the point in my question about editors was irrelevant. So, if there is no way to do exactly what I want, I guess @fedorqui 's answer  is the best I could get.